# linear algebra: if $A$ is in span $B $ is span $A$ in span $B$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two group of vectors under vector space $V$ , $A$ and $B$

If $A$ is in the span of $B$ is span $A$ in the span of $B$?

and also:

If $A$ is in the span of $B$ and $B$ is in the span of $A$ is $span (A) = span (B)?$

Comment: The second part is saying that if $span(A)\subset span(B)$ and $span(B)\subset span(A)$ then $span(A)=span(B)$. This is a property of the equality of sets. It is true. To do the first part take a linear combination of elements of $A$: $\sum\alpha_i a_i$, for $a_i\in A$. Since $A\subset span(B)$ then each $a_i$ is a linear combination $a_i=\sum_j\beta_{ij}b_j$ of elements of $B$. Putting this in the first linear combination you get that $\sum\alpha_i a_i=\sum_i\sum_j\beta_{ij}b_j$. This shows that the elements of $span(A)$ are in $span(B)$.

Answer (score 1):

Take an element of $\sum_{i=0}^n \lambda_i x_i\in \text{span}(A)$ where $\lambda_i\in\Bbb{K}$ and $x_i\in A$. Then write each $x_i$ as a finite linear combination of elements of $B$ (this can be done since $A\subseteq \text{span}(B)$). Conclude that $\text{span}(A)\subseteq \text{span}(B)$.

The second part directly follows from the first part.

Comment: can you explain why the second part directly follows from the first part?

Comment: From the first part you deduce that span(A)$\subseteq$span(B) since A is in the span of B and similarly span(B)$\subseteq$span(A). So you have both set inclusions hence the sets have to be equal.

Comment: sorry ill rephrase how did you get from $A \subseteq span(B)$ to $span(A) \subseteq span(B)$

Comment: That's the first part of your question. The answer is the first paragraph of my answer.